# Calling java non-static method in Clojure

Tags: java, methods, clojure

Am i thinking wrongly about something: Clojure imports upon starting REPL all the Classes in the java.lang package. So one should be able to call methods from these classes without importing them. Now i am trying to play a bit with different classes of java.lang package, and i cant call some public methods in the form `(.Method)`, for example (.[totalMemory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory())) of the Runtime Class throws IllegalArgumentException. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you typing in to the REPL?

Comment: Imports in java don't work like that. All instance methods need to be associated with a target object. Do something like `(.totalMemory (Runtime/getRuntime))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
(.totalMemory (Runtime/getRuntime))
```

Clojure does not automatically import all methods from all classes in `java.lang`. Also, the method `totalMemory` in class `Runtime` is not a static method, so you need to specify the instance to call the method on.

You get the instance by calling the static method `getRuntime` from class `Runtime`.

See [Clojure - Java Interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop) for information about how to call a Java method from Clojure.

Comment: i have no experience in java, this means java static methods don't need an argument (like `Math/PI`) and the non-static ones should get an arg?

Comment: Non-static methods must be called on an instance of a class (an object). Static methods can be called on the class itself and don't need to be called on an object.

Comment: Could you explain shortly what an object is, and how could i know which objects are available for certain methods(for example `getRuntime` for `totalMemory`)?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri That's a new question, not a comment on this one.

Comment: @AmirTeymuri Have a look at Oracle's Java tutorials: [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). The [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) lists the classes and objects available in the standard Java library.